# Как внести изменения в нужную ячейку в tableViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iphone

У меня есть tableViewController и для него я создал отдельный класс. В этом классе есть метод:

```swift
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomPostCellTableViewCell
        cell.likeBTN.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.likeBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedVC.likeClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
```

Я могу через cell обращаться к любому кастомному элементу ячейки. Но внутри данной функции. Но у меня есть ещё одна функция, которая срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку в ячейке. В этой функции я получаю номер ячейки. Но как мне теперь обратиться к элементу нужной ячейки и изменить его из этой функции (ниже)?

```swift
    @IBAction func likeClick (sender: UIButton){
        let indx = NSIndexPath(index: sender.tag)
        print(indx)
    }
```

Задача следующая: у меня в таблице выводятся посты в каждой ячейке. И в каждом посте есть кнопка лайк. При нажатии на кнопку должно меняться количество лайков. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: что пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: Что именно не получается, обновить нужную ячейку (reload)/ отправить какой-либо запрос/ изменить что-то в модели?

Comment: @VAndrJ я попробовал в функции likeClick объявить переменную let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomPostCellTableViewCell
только подставил вместо indexPath полученный из тега индекс.

Comment: В результате выдаёт ошибку. Так что там даже до обновления не дошло. Я попросту даже не знаю как правильно обратиться к нужной ячейке.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko я чуть выше в комменте написал, что я пробовал. Но по сути я это сделал наобум, так как не знаю как нужно обращаться определённому элементу любой ячейки из другой функции? Т.е. например изменить значение текстового поля ячейки номер 10, чтобы оно отобразилось сразу же. Про обновление вроде бы я в курсе, но до обновления надо ведь сначала значение изменить в ячейке.

Comment: я тогда еще раз повторю вопрос заданный @VAndrJ : не получается изменить количество лайков в ячейке (во вью), или изменить значение в модели?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko у меня просто ошибка в логе выскакивает и всё. Конкретно текст ошибки сейчас пока не могу привести так как мака сейчас под рукой нет. Вечером гляну. Но у меня подозрения, что я вообще это неправильно делаю. И у меня вопрос как это правильно делается. И что значит изменить значения в модели?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko вот, как я пытаюсь менять значения в ячейке:   

@ IBAction func likeClick (sender: UIButton){
        let indx = NSIndexPath(index: sender.tag)
        print(indx)
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indx) as! CustomPostCellTableViewCell
        //cell.likeBTN.setTitle("20", forState: .Normal)
        //self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indx], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    }

Comment: Слеши я поставил временно, чтобы пока работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем до меня дошло, что мне и не нужно получать доступ к ячейке. Мне просто нужно внести изменения в нужный элемент массива и просто потом обновить ячейку.

```swift
    @IBAction func likeClick (sender: UIButton){
        let ind = sender.tag
        let indx = NSIndexPath(forRow: ind, inSection: 0)
        print(indx)
        allposts[ind].postlikes = 100

        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indx], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    }
```

А ошибка возникала из-за того, что NSIndexPath был неправильно задан. Ему надо задавать номер секции (в моём случае всегда 0) и номер строки.